# Create a new page in scribble with pdf/latex backend

Tags: pdf, latex, racket, scribble

In latex, I can create a new page with the `\newpage` command. There does not seem to be any way to do this directly in Scribble (at least not for a PDF/Latex back end.)

So, how can I force scribble to make me new page for my document?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is doable. It is however a bit clunky, and only works when rendering to a latex file (or pdf file), as this does not make sense for a webpage. The original way I had to do this went into LaTeX. However, it turns out there is a way to do this staying entirely in scribble. Whichever you prefer is obviously going to depend on context, so I've put both options here.

## Option 1: Entirely in Scribble Option

The way this works is to use scribble [styles](http://docs.racket-lang.org/scribble/core.html?q=style#%28tech._style%29) with a string for its name. Doing so turns the style into a LaTeX environment or command (depending on what you put it into.) In our case, we want a command, so we will use an [`element`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/scribble/core.html?q=style#%28def._%28%28lib._scribble%2Fcore..rkt%29._element%29%29). The resulting code will look something like this:

```
(define (newpage)
  (make-element (style "newpage" '())
                '()))
```

Now you can use the `newpage` function wherever you want and latex will insert a `\newpage`.

## Option 2: Insert raw latex:

The other option is to insert a bit of raw latex code in your scribble file. To do this, you first need to create a file, say: `textstyle.tex`, and in this file, put:

```
\newcommand{\identity}[1]{#1}
```

The name of the file doesn't matter, and if it has other commands in it too is fine. This is just to create a latex command that just evaluates to the same text its given.

Next, somewhere in your scribble code, you can create the following two functions:

```
(define (exact . items)
  (make-element (make-style "identity" '(exact-chars))
                items))

(define (newpage)
  (exact "\\newpage"))
```

The first function defines `exact`, which we can use to insert latex code. This works because The `exact-chars` style passes the characters into latex verbatim, and does not pass it through any sort of pre-processor. We need the `identity` stile here so that latex has something to put the text in.

The `newpage` function is then translated directly into `\newpage` in latex. Just call it where you want in your code as `(newpage)` (or `@newpage[]`/`@(newpage)` when using at-expressions).

Finally, you need to tell scribble where to find the `texstyle.tex` file. You can do that with the `++style` flag when running scribble. Altogether, your command should look something like:

```
scribble --pdf ++style texstyle.tex mydocument.scrbl
```

As an extra, if you want the document to compile for any back end and not just latex/pdf, you can use [`cond-element`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/scriblib/render-cond.html?q=cond-elem#%28form._%28%28lib._scriblib%2Frender-cond..rkt%29._cond-element%29%29). That way you can just have it be an empty element in any other backend:

```
(define (exact-latex . items)
  (cond-element [latex
                  (make-element (make-style "identity" '(exact-chars))
                                items)]
                [else ....]))

(define (newpage)
  (exact-latex "\\newpage"))
```